# Why does enabling timer to auto start disable my stop and reset buttons?

Tags: javascript, html

Thanks for any help here, not sure what's going on - but when I enable the `timer();` line in order to automatically start the timer when the page is loaded, it disables the stop and reset buttons. I tried to only include relevant code here. Can anyone shed some light on why this is happening? Thank you in advance!

```js
const startstop = () => {};

var clicks = 0;

function onClick() {
  clicks += 1;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
};

const input = parseInt(prompt("Enter a SAMS number: "));
var SAMSINPUT = input;
//console.log(SAMSINPUT);
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = SAMSINPUT;
var goal = 0;
//var SAMSINPUTtest = parseInt(document.getElementById("input"));
//setInterval(function doIncrement() {
//  goal += 1;
//}, SAMSINPUT * 1000); // *1000 to convert from seconds to milliseconds
var output2 = document.getElementById('output2');
setInterval(function doIncrement() {
  goal += 1;
  output2.innerHTML = goal.toString();
}, SAMSINPUT * 1000)

var timerDiv = document.getElementById('timerValue'),
  start = document.getElementById('start'),
  stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
  reset = document.getElementById('reset'),
  t;

// Get time from cookie
var cookieTime = null; //getCookie('time'); // for test

// If timer value is saved in the cookie
if (cookieTime != null && cookieTime != '00:00:00') {
  var savedCookie = cookieTime;
  var initialSegments = savedCookie.split('|');
  var savedTimer = initialSegments[0];
  var timerSegments = savedTimer.split(':');
  var seconds = parseInt(timerSegments[2]),
    minutes = parseInt(timerSegments[1]),
    hours = parseInt(timerSegments[0]);
  timer();
  document.getElementById('timerValue').textContent = savedTimer;
  $('#stop').removeAttr('disabled');
  $('#reset').removeAttr('disabled');
} else {
  var seconds = 0,
    minutes = 0,
    hours = 0;
  timerDiv.textContent = "00:00:00";
}

// New Date object for the expire time
var curdate = new Date();
var exp = new Date();

// Set the expire time
exp.setTime(exp + 2592000000);

function add() {

  seconds++;
  if (seconds >= 60) {
    seconds = 0;
    minutes++;
    if (minutes >= 60) {
      minutes = 0;
      hours++;
    }
  }

  timerDiv.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") +
    ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") +
    ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

  // Set a 'time' cookie with the current timer time and expire time object.
  var timerTime = timerDiv.textContent.replace("%3A", ":");
  //console.log('timerTime', timerTime);
  //setCookie('time', timerTime + '|' + curdate, exp);

  timer();
}

function timer() {
  t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
}

timer(); // autostart timer

/* Start button */
start.onclick = timer;

/* Stop button */
stop.onclick = function() {
  clearTimeout(t);
}

/* Clear button */
reset.onclick = function() {
  timerDiv.textContent = "00:00:00";
  seconds = 0;
  minutes = 0;
  hours = 0;
  //setCookie('time', "00:00:00", exp);
}

/**
 * Javascript Stopwatch: Button Functionality
 * 
 */

$('#start').on('click', function() {
  $('#stop').removeAttr('disabled');
  $('#reset').removeAttr('disabled');
});

$('#stop').on('click', function() {
  $(this).prop('disabled', 'disabled');
});

$('#reset').on('click', function() {
  $(this).prop('disabled', 'disabled');
});

/**
 * Javascript Stopwatch: Cookie Functionality
 * 
 */


function setCookie(name, value, expires) {
  document.cookie = name + "=" + value + "; path=/" + ((expires == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString());
}

function getCookie(name) {
  var cname = name + "=";
  var dc = document.cookie;

  if (dc.length > 0) {
    begin = dc.indexOf(cname);
    if (begin != -1) {
      begin += cname.length;
      end = dc.indexOf(";", begin);
      if (end == -1) end = dc.length;
      return unescape(dc.substring(begin, end));
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: powderblue;
}

p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body onload="startstop();">
  <p> SAMS VALUE:
    <a id="output"></a>
  </p>

  <p> GOAL:
    <a id="output2"></a>
  </p>

  <button style="background-color:green" type="button" onClick="onClick()">ACTUAL</button>
  <p>Actual Count: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div id="timeContainer" class="well well-sm">
          <time id="timerValue"></time>
        </div>
        <div id="timerButtons">
          <button id="start" class="btn btn-success">START</button>
          <button id="stop" class="btn btn-danger" disabled="disabled">STOP</button>
          <button id="reset" class="btn btn-default" disabled="disabled">RESET</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hello. Welcome to SO. A full snippet would help us debug your code.

Comment: If you need a "ticking" counter, you should use `setInterval` and not `setTimeout` as you use, because setTimeout will fire only 1 time

Comment: edited to include the full code @IslamElshobokshy

Comment: @Anton Sorry I am not very good at this, I've edited the code as islam had asked to include the full code I'm using - would that still be viable even though I use setInterval for a different purpose elsewhere in the code?